# I have to replicate all config file for each environment

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I try to add some config in **config/*** directory.
I'll use a very simple example, to illustrate the problem, but keep in mind that this problem occur for every **.yaml** config files for any services. I am not able to make inheritance between config files.

So in **services.yaml** I have this code :

```
#config/services.yaml
parameters:
    app.debug: 0
    smtp.user: ''
    app.locale: '%kernel.default_locale%'
    app.product.number_per_page: 20
    container.dumper.inline_factories: true
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        bind:
            $locale: '%kernel.default_locale%'
            $product_per_page: '%app.product.number_per_page%'
```

And then i try to access `$product_per_page` into my controller :

```
#src/Controller/myController.php
public function listProduct(int $product_per_page){
   dump($product_per_page);
   die();
}
```

When I execute this code, it give me the following errror :

> Could not resolve argument $product_per_page of
> "App\Controller\ProductController::listproduct()", maybe you forgot to
> register the controller as a service or missed tagging it with the
> "controller.service_arguments"?

So I have to copy this config files (`config/services.yaml`), and then paste it into config/`services_dev.yaml, services_prod.yaml, services_test.yaml`

And then it is working, but this is not suitable at all...

Because I have to do that for every config files... So i copy and paste in every environnement each time I update ANY configuration.

Of course, I have try to `cache:clear` and `composer update`, but nothing do.

I was expecting Symfony read the file as explain [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments) but it is not working for me.

I have try to create another Symfony project, and now it is working in this one. But I want to understand what is wrong ? Is there a thing I have done which have result into a bug that cannot being correct even ater updating Symfony, even after having update composer, even after having clear the cache.

**I can't believe there's nothing to do but to create a new Symfony project in which you copy the files from the old one.**

Comment: Don't really understand your question.  The original error is because your controller was not being picked up as a service.  Typically, when using autowire, you have a resource: '../src/Controller/' line in your services.yaml file which takes care of registering your controllers.  Do you still have that section?

Comment: I'm maybe not enough clear. As I say, I have create a test Symfony project inside which I do the same thing as in my current project, and it is working as it should be. I now want to know if i'm missing something, if there is a way to clear services config, clean Symfony project or anything. Because what I did should've work but actually is not working. I think my question is clear enough

Comment: As posted, your config/services.yaml file is not going to work and will fail exactly as the posted error message indicates.  To me at least, this talk about a new project and additional service files is very confusing as I don't see how it relates to the error in your question.  It is possible that you are talking about repeating the _defaults section in each services.yaml file?  If so then yes, each file is it own unit of work and each file needs it's own default section.  Likewise each file will need it's own resources sections if applicable.  By design.

Comment: @Cerad Ok I see, but this : https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#configuration-environments
say the opposite, as it stand that there exist an inheritance between the config files.

Sorry, i know this is a confusing problem, i have try to explain it the best that I can.

But if you want to do it simple, my question is "Inheritance between config file is not working, how to make it work without having to create a new clean Symfony project"

Comment: And as i say, i have to create a configuration file like ``services_dev.yaml`` to make it work, instead of inside my new test Symfony project. So there is something different between the two project and I can't figure what it is

Comment: I spent a bit of time looks for where it is explicitly stated that must repeat the defaults section in the docs and did not come up with anything.  But in the [original announcement](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-simpler-service-configuration), we find "The new services._defaults option lets you set the value of the public, tags and autowire options for all the services defined in a single file:". Note the use of the word "single".

Comment: Other types of config files such as those found under config/packages are just arrays and processed very differently.  If you want we can go to chat and you can show me which files(s) are not working.

Comment: Well so ``_default`` section is the only section which will not be inherited by all the ``services_env.yaml`` ? This is weird. I don't know how to chat :|

Comment: Inheritance is the wrong concept.  Each services*.yaml file is independent and they each get processed individually.  However, everything does end up in one master container so a parameter, for example, can be used in a different file.  _defaults only apply when processing the current file.  Keep in mind that it is a bit unusual to have multiple environment based service files at the application level.  Maybe you could post your test project to github and we could discuss in chat.

Comment: You might also take a look at PHP based service configuration.  That gives you the full power of code and might be less magical than yaml files.  Using PHP seems to be the direction Symfony is heading.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219969/discussion-between-vincent-philippe-and-cerad).